# Can't execute flutter code from VS Code to android emulator

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO3h5.jpg)
I recently started learning Flutter. I started on Android Studio and downloaded an Emulator there. Then I decided to move to Visual Studio Code.

On VSC, I can open the emulator and the emulator is showing on the Status Bar but I cant't run the code using the emulator. Someone please help

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. #1 Please provide a MRE (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with snippets of relevant code (HTML,CSS,etc.) so we can better help you thank you. #2 Please identify a specific and unique question in your post.

Comment: @LaurentC "How to" Questions, Questions about technical difference, or how to navigate a tool, etc. do not need code, nor minimal reproducible examples. In fact the ones that absolutely need those are debug Questions, as specified in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You may also check out  [Is it always a good idea to demand the OP “post some code”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286757/is-it-always-a-good-idea-to-demand-the-op-post-some-code/286760#286760). I'd rather not have Stack Overflow be only debug Questions.

Comment: @LaurentC Also, if you're not going to address the specifics of a Question with a comment, then there's no reason to post a comment. This particular one is unrelated to HTML and CSS. It's also very specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your emulator is connected you have type the command flutter run for that Press Ctrl+Shift+` which will open up the terminal where you can type the command